# Why the entry details below "Personal Details" section is not getting printed?

Tags: moderncv

This is the code that I'm writing for my CV.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       

\moderncvstyle{classic}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{136.00005pt}                
\ifxetexorluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
  \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
  \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
  \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put (0in,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pexels-anete-lusina-6331082.jpg}}%
}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 


                         
                     


\begin{document}

\section{Personal Details}
\cventry{Name}{XYZ}{}


\cventry{Email}{XYZ123@gmail.com}{}

\section{Education}
\cventry{2020-2023}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{\textit{First Division}}{Description}  
\cventry{2019}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}
\cventry{2017}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{}

\end{document}
```

The problem is details that I have entered below the section of "Personal Details" is not getting printed/compiled in PDF output. I cannot see the problem, can someone please help?

Acknowledgements: the packages used in this code has been taken from a template available on internet.

Comment: you shouldn't ignore errors. \cventry has 6 arguments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I mean, can I keep {} blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems. @ulrike-fischer has already pointed out the first: `\cventry` has 6 arguments, and they are *all* required.

> @UlrikeFischer I mean, can I keep {} blank?

Yes, you may keep them blank, but you must include all 6. For example, `\cventry{Name}{XYZ}{}` should be `\cventry{Name}{XYZ}{}{}{}{}`.

The second problem is that you never added your name to the CV using the package's name commands (either with `\name{}{}` or with `\firstname{}` and `\familyname{}`). This is also required for `moderncv` documents to compile, though the package's documentation doesn't actually say this.

After making these changes, your document compiles and looks like this. I replaced `pexels-anete-lusina-6331082.jpg` with a placeholder image since I obviously don't have your image file. For future reference, please replace all imported images with placeholders when asking questions on TeX SE.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setlength{\footskip}{136.00005pt}
\ifxetexorluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
    \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
    \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put (0in,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}%
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Personal Details}

\cventry{Name}{XYZ}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{Email}{XYZ123@gmail.com}{}{}{}{}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2020-2023}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{\textit{First Division}}{Description}
\cventry{2019}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{}{}
\cventry{2017}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an aside, I kept the majority of your document as-is, but FYI you shouldn't use `\cventry` for personal details. `moderncv` has commands specifically for those (`\name`, `\email`, `\address`, `\phone`, etc.).